# How to connect to a ssh server by using android adb shell?

Tags: android, python, ssh, adb

Im trying to establish a ssh connection on android to another linux pc and autorun commands client sided to the host.

Since i haven't found any way to connect by using adb on its own, i'd consider using python or any other programing/scriptinglanguage which is preinstalled on android.

Unfortunately, those preinstalled languages, have a different usage. Such as "python" or "pip" is not a command when using adb. But it supports executing .py files. I want to import Modules like Paramiko.

Comment: you can install an https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-install-an-ssh-server-on-your-android-phone/  and then use your favorit scripting language. so mainly you should be able using the android.runtime.exec('') command to automate the installation inside your own app

Comment: i want to connect FROM my ANDROID device by using adb shell TO a different external SSH server. Im sorry if i didnt explained my case detailed enough or didnt understood your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly the same problem I'm struggling on. But unfortunately I haven't found a simple, easy way after I googled for about 10 minutes.
But some answers about Dropbear's binary inspired me.

Here is the method which solved my problem:

**Requirements:**

1. you need a rooted android device
2. please install Termux on it  (Termux is brilliant!!!)
3. open Termux and install openssh

   ```
   pkg update
   pkg install openssh
   ```

**Steps to use ssh in adb shell:**

```
adb shell
su
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib
PATH=$PATH:/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin
ssh your-ip-address -l user
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you that you should use Fredrik Fornwal 's Termux.
https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/Remote_Access

adb over SSH is unsafe for android. Consider yourself banged up in an exploited wifi network. Someone ssh-s to your ADB enabled phone and you know that.

i just found this:
https://www.jnchen.com/blog/2012/11/tunnelling-adb
walking around with an adb,ssh enabled phone is not a good idea from the perspective of security.

Comment: `adb over SSH is unsafe for android` `walking around with an adb,ssh enabled phone is not a good idea from the perspective of security` why would that be the case? It's nice to give an insight about what can go wrong when claiming that something is insecure. It's not clear to me from your sentence who is tunneling who, etc.